# Serializar una lista con nodos y objetos genéricos

Tags: java, serialización

Tengo que hacer una clase lista de forma artesanal, con una serie de nodos que tengan un objeto tipo T. Hasta aquí funciona bien.
Aquí el código.

```
package Controlador;

import java.io.Serializable;
public class Lista <T> implements Serializable
{
    private Nodo first; 

    public Lista()
    {   }

    public Lista(Nodo first)
    {
        this();
        this.first=first;
    }

    public void initializeLista(T o)
    {
        first=new Nodo(o);
    }


    public Nodo getFirst()
    {
        return first;
    }

    public T getFirstT()
    {
        return (T) first.getCurrent();
    }


    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return first==null; //Or return size()==0;
    }

    public int size()
    {
        Nodo aux=first;

        int count=0;
        while(aux!=null)
        {
            count++;
            aux=aux.getNext();
        }
        return count;
    }

    public T getNodo(int index)
    {
    Nodo aux=first;
    int count=0;
    while(count!=index)
    {
        count++;
        aux=aux.getNext();
    }

        return (T) aux.getCurrent();
    }

    public Nodo getLast()
    {
        Nodo n=first;
        while(n.getNext()!=null)
            n=n.getNext();
        return n;
    }

    public void insert(T o)
    {       
        if (this.size()==0)
        {
            initializeLista(o);
            //System.out.println("I");
        }
        else
        {
            Nodo l=getLast();
            //System.out.println("O");
            Nodo n=new Nodo(o);
            l.add(n);
        }
    }

}
//Point 4
class Nodo <T> //implements Serializable //Ya he probado a ponerle Serializable por si acaso. No ha servido
{
    private T current;
    private Nodo next;
    private Nodo previous;


    public Nodo(T object)
    {
        current=object;
    }

    public Nodo(T object, Nodo previous)
    {
        this(object);
        this.previous=previous;
    }

    public void add(Nodo next)
    {
        this.next=next;
    }

    public void midInsert(Nodo next)
    {
        Nodo n=this.next;
        this.next=next;
        this.next.add(next);
    }

    public Nodo getNext()
    {
        return next;
    }

    public Nodo getPrevious()
    {
        return previous;
    }

    public void deleteNodo()
    {
        this.previous.next=this.next;
    }

    public T getCurrent()
    {
        return current;
    }


}
```

Puedo crear nodos sin ningún problema, no he podido probar si recuperarlos después, tiene pinta de que sí podré, pero el problema es que, tengo que tener la posibilidad de escribir esa lista, con todos sus nodos, guardarlo en un fichero, y posteriormente volverlo a cargar para visualizarlo.

El código que he hecho después de intentar seguir 35 guías distintas en internet se resume en:

```
public static boolean writeList(Lista l)
    {
        ObjectOutputStream salida=null;
        try
        {
            System.err.println("Log1 "+getFile());
            salida = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(getFile())); 
            System.err.println("Log2");
            salida.writeObject(l); //<-- Aquí falla
            System.err.println("Log3");
            return true;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        { return false; }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                salida.close();
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {               }
        }
    }
```

getFile() apunta a una String que tiene la ruta absoluta al fichero.
El fallo lo da en writeObject, aunque tiene importado java.io.*
¿Qué es lo que hago mal?
¿Qué tengo que hacer para repararlo?

Ah, el fichero existe en la ruta pasada por la String, el programa tiene permisos, y el disco duro espacio más que de sobra.

[Edit]
Como respuesta a Pablo Lozano, aquí está el printstacktrace

```
   java.io.NotSerializableException: Modelo.Account
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at Controlador.OpenFile.writeList(OpenFile.java:66)
    at Vista.MainFrame.saveFile(MainFrame.java:213)
    at Vista.MainFrame.jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(MainFrame.java:104)
    at Vista.MainFrame.jMenuItem3ActionPerformed(MainFrame.java:108)
    at Vista.MainFrame.access$200(MainFrame.java:7)
    at Vista.MainFrame$3.actionPerformed(MainFrame.java:62)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Fue solo una broma. Me causo risa esa expresión, es todo.

Comment: Por suerte, no es el caso, es solo un trabajo de clase en el que me han mandado a usar como 7 cosas que no uso desde hace un montón de años, a la vez.

¡Por cierto, que rápido lees los comentarios! Borraste el original cuando se me olvidó pulsar shift en el anterior.

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir el error que te da?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres serializar una lista, los elementos tienen que ser serializables. Al usar genéricos, puedes obligar a que el tipo sea serializable:

```
class Lista<T extends Serializable>  implements Serializable{

    private Nodo<T> cabeza;

    ...
}
```

Tu error dice que estás intentando serializar una clase llamada `Modelo.Account`que no has descrito, así que asumo que es algo que has metido en tus nodos. Asegúrate de que esa clase sea también serializable.